# Connect with Facebook Codeigniter

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I'm trying to add Facebook SDK PHP to my Codeigniter project,but **I get an error**:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more
>   of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match
>   the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of
>   one of the App's domains.

I searched on this website and google too, but nothing like my problem. I also have set domain in developer.facebook.com as http://localhost/ . Can anyone help me ? It's the only problem.

Comment: maybe it won't work on localhost.

Comment: Facebook SDK PHP works on localhost.

Comment: You need to also specify `Valid OAuth redirect URIs` under Settings->Advanced.

Comment: Now seems to work, but I set as `http://localhost/login` and still error. Then I checked Facebook Login URL and I saw my link is something like `http://127.0.0.1/login` . I set this link and now Facebook make redirect. How can I set my URL link and create a session of userID because this return create no session. Thank you !

Comment: Yes facebook redirect will not create session for your application rather it will return you with the token by using it you can add the user and create the session as required